# NHibernate CallSessionContext vs ThreadStaticSessionContext

Tags: wcf, nhibernate

Is someone able to explain NHibernate's CallSessionContext, and contrast it to ThreadStaticSessionContext.

The best explaination I have been able to find, has been from the [NHibernate documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html?bcsi_scan_F246D99C5E000224=0&bcsi_scan_filename=index.html#architecture-current-session) :

> - NHibernate.Context.CallSessionContext- current sessions are tracked by CallContext. You are responsible to
>     bind and unbind an  ISession instance
>     with static methods of class
>     CurrentSessionContext.
> - NHibernate.Context.ThreadStaticSessionContext - current session is stored in a thread-static variable. This context
>     only supports one session factory. You
>     are responsible to bind and unbind an
>     ISession instance with static methods
>     of class CurrentSessionContext.

I am familiar with the WebSessionContext, as my usual use of NHibernate is in web applications. This time I am building a WCF service, to be hosted in IIS, and am trying to determine which implementation of ICurrentSessionContext is preferable.

I would like to know the implications of choosing one vs the other, both in this particular case (WCF service), and in general for future reference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6653366/189429

Answer (score 2):

NHibernate 3 has a WCF-specific implementation, `WcfOperationSessionContext`

Comment: Thanks Diego. I am currently using NHibernate 2.1, but I downloaded the source for v3 and this looks like what I was hoping for. 
I think I will add the WcfOperationSessionContext class to our solution.
I am going to leave theis question as unanswered for now, as I would still be interested to have the CallSessionContext and ThreadStaticSessionContext explained.